# Asymptotics of the number of diagonalizable matrix over a finite field.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, asymptotics

Let $F_q$ be a finite field of $q$ elements. I know that the number of diagonalizable matrices of size $n$ with coefficients in $F_q$ is :$\DeclareMathOperator{\\Card}{Card}$

$$N_{n, q} = \sum_{n_1+ \dots + n_q = n} \frac{\Card(GL_n(F_q))}{ \Card(GL_{n_1}(F_q)) \times \dots \times \Card(GL_{n_q}(F_q))}$$

with $\Card(GL_n(Fq)) = (q^n -1)\times (q^n - q) \times \dots \times (q^n - q^{n-1})$

I wonder if there is a way to estimate the proportion of diagolizable matrix : $N_{n, q}/q^{n^2}$ for $q \to \infty$ (with $n$ fixed). The expression seem very complicated to me and I don't know how to start.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure how to go about it, but I would suspect that the leading term comes from the conjugacy classes of matrices whose eigenvalues are all distinct. You’d get $\frac{1}{n!}|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)/D_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|\cdot (q-1)(q-2)\ldots (q-n) \sim \frac{|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|}{n!} \sim q^{n^2}/n!$ as $q$ goes to infinity with $n$ fixed.

Comment: Actually I know where the above comes from: basically, matrices with nonseparable characteristic polynomial or that are singular vanish at a particular polynomial in $n^2$ variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, so there are at most $C(n)q^{n^2-1}$ of them, where $C(n)$ depends on $n$ only.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you explain why there is at most $C(n) q^{n^2-1}$ of such roots ?

Comment: The general statement is the following: let $P$ be a nonzero polynomial in $n$ variables of maximal degree wrt one variable at most $d$ over a field $F$ with $q$ elements. Then $P$ has at most $C(n,d)q^{n-1}$ zeros. The proof is by induction over $n$: write (up to re-ordering the variables) $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^d{a_i(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n^i}$ where some $a_i$ is nonzero with degree at most $d$. For every $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ but $C(n-1,d)q^{n-2}$ (roots of $a_i$), $t \longmapsto P(x,t)$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree $\le d$ so has $\leq d$ roots. (Cont’d)

Comment: In the remaining cases, there are at most $q$ roots for $t$, so this makes $C(n-1,d)q^{n-2}$ solutions total. Thus $C(n,d)=(d+1)C(n-1,d)$ works, ie $C(n,d)=(d+1)^{n-1}d$ works. In our case, we have $n^2$ variables, are over a field with $q$ elements, and the polynomial has degree $n$ (determinant)+ $n(2n-1)$ (resultant of a polynomial of degree $n$ whose coefficients are polynomials of degree at most $n$), so is a sole function of $n$.